# How to compile my program with older versions of libraries for more compatibility

Tags: c, linux, libraries

I'm making an application and I want to distribute the executable itself, but when I compile on my computer (using Arch Linux) it compiles with what I believe are the newest libraries available. This creates the issue that when I try and run said program in my vm, the glibc version is outdated. Is there any program or method to compile using the oldest/most backwards compatible versions of my required libraries so that my app works on as many Linux desktops as possible? Or should I just statically link and tank the size? Thanks.

Comment: What about using containers ?

Comment: Looks promising I'll look into it.

Comment: Even if you link against older lib version, this may fail to work on newer distros. As this, I tend to bind it statically. If a "container" is an option, size didn't matter at all :-)

Comment: You can always compile with static libraries so that your executable contains all the code you use and then it won't use any libraries installed on the system.